# Como criar um tag semelhante a uma já existente?

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tags

Tentei criar a *tag* HTTPS em [pergunta que acho que era importante diferenciá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47194/101), mas o sistema não permitiu por já existir a *tag* HTTP. E me sugeriu abrir uma pergunta no meta para que isto fosse feito. Só moderadores podem fazê-lo? Tem que habilitar alguma coisa no site?

Note que nem deixa criar a *tag*. Mas deixa criar [arvore](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arvore) quando já tem [árvore](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a1rvore).

Comment: Não seria melhor HTTP + SSL?

Comment: Quem garante que o HTTP está usando SSL? O SO tem as duas *tags*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O sistema me deixou criar a tag, deve ser porque sou moderador. Portanto, o procedimento no futuro para quem passar por esse problema é fazer como o @bigown e postar no meta, ou sinalizar a pergunta para que um dos moderadores resolva.